# JavaFX - Using Progressbar on dynamically loaded Gridpane

Tags: javafx

I'm using a GridPane, where I'm loading my data from a DB to the Pane, creating rows and columns dynamically. It works fine, but sometimes, if there is a lot of stuff (about 30 rows and 30 columns, and every cell has a EventListener) to load, it takes more than a second to see the loaded stuff.

So, I thought, that it will be great to add a ProgressBar or a ProgressIndicator. I tried that, but I realized that it does not depend on the loops, which are filling and creating the dynamic GridPane, but on the fact that the "loading and applying" takes a lot of time. My ProgressIndicator jumps from 0 to 100 and that's not what I want.

Do you have some ideas how to solve that problem? I read some articles about Preloaders, and I'm looking for a similar functionality, but I can't use Preloaders for that problem.

Best regards,

Edit: Now I got a solution, which works, but I don't think that someone else would write such code :S.
I created a class called LoaderDienstplan:

```
public class LoaderDienstplan extends Task {
    //Some member variables for starting call() method

    @Override
    protected Object[] call() throws Exception{
        // calling DB and service
        updateProgress(1,1);
        return; // Returning an ObjectArray with Lists,Data and a reference to my  Controllerclass
    }
    @Override
    public void run(){
        final Object[] b = call();
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            //Updating GridPane
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to show the progress and can you get an actual percentage or do you just want a bouncing bar? `setProgress(-1)`, gives the indeterminate, bouncing back and forth look.

Comment: Well, the problem is, that my Application is freezing, and my question is, how to "access" that state, so I'll be able to refresh my progressBar. I put already my method into a class, which implements Runnable. But nevertheless, can't get the progress out of it.

Comment: You set the progress indeterminate before doing your update then setting it back to 0 after it's finished.  The same idea works with Cobbles' answer.  Look at some examples or post your code if you want the `Task` to [`updateProgress`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#updateProgress-double-double-).

Comment: How can I achieve your solution? Well, I set the progress to -1 before calling the thread and then I called it back, but the problem is, that it changed of course only once per "event", so I'll see only the last added progress.
Btw, can you show me the solution with implementing Task to my class?

Now I'm doing exactly that, what Cobbles wrote, I'm calling the thread in my ControllerClass, passing the GridPane and so parameter to the constructor and then starting the process.

Comment: After reading and trying to find a solution, I think I know, why it does not work. My method, which is loading and filling the Gridpane is accessing the DB in a loop. So reading the information out of the DB takes a lot of time. I used the System.getNanoTime method to check how long my method needs to load. Unfortunately it takes about 0.5 seconds and without accessing the DB it takes only 0.05 seconds.
So, in my opinion, I need to extract the Service from the GUI, so I'll compute the time-intensive parts in the service, using Task or Thread and then finally passing the data to the Grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class LoaderDienstplan extends Task {

MyInterface listener;
//Some member variables for starting call() method

@Override
protected Object[] call() throws Exception{
    // calling DB and service
    updateProgress(1,1);
    return; // Returning an ObjectArray with Lists,Data and a reference to my  Controllerclass
}

public void setListener(MyInterface listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    final Object[] b = call();
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Updating GridPane
             listener.updateGUI(something);
        }
    });
}
}
```

And the interface:

```
public interface MyInterface {
     void updateGUI(Something something);
     void loadingFinished();
}
```

And from your Controller class, **must** `implements MyInterface`:

```
LoaderDienstplan load = new LoaderDienstplan(...);
load.setListener(this);
```

Make this class:

```
public class Loader implements Runnable {

   private final MyController listener;
   private final List<File> stuff;
   public DoubleProperty progressProperty;

   public Loader(MyController listener, List<File> stuffToLoad) {
     this.stuff = stuffToLoad;
     progressProperty = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
     this.listener = listener;
   }

   private void updateProgress(double value, double max) {
     progressProperty.set(value / max);
   }

   public DoubleProperty progressProperty() {
      return progressProperty;
   }

   @Override
   public void run() { 
      Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
             //load the stuffs
          }
      });
      //each time you load another stuff, do:
      updateProgress(index, totalAmountOfStuffs);

      //when finished, do:
      listener.finished();
   }
}
```

Put a veil and an indicator around the GridPane, like this (i made the veil (`Region`) and indicator (`ProgressIndicator`) from the JavaFX SceneBuilder):

```
//lets say your progress indicator is called progressIndicator and the shaded `Region` is called veil
progressIndicator.setMaxSize(150, 150);
veil.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)");
```

And run the Loader class from another thread like this:

```
private void startLoading() {
   progressIndicator.setVisible(true);
   veil.setVisible(true);
   Loader loader = new Loader(this, stuffToLoad);
   progressIndicator.progressProperty().bind(loader.progressProperty());
   new Thread(loader).start();
}

@Override
public void finished() {
   progressIndicator.setVisible(false);
   veil.setVisible(false);
}
```

What it looks like for me:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried that. But the problem is, that the content of my run() method is filling the GridPane with rows and columns. My application freezes for that moment, so your idea does not even appear in that moment, also even if I try to add "thread.sleep()" to "updateProgress". I have to access the loading javafx thread, but i don't know how, do you know what I mean?

Comment: My apologies, I forgot to add a few bits to the code. I added the binding of the progressIndicator to the Loader class, and the Platform.runLater method which means the GUI changes occur on the JavaFX application thread which (I hope) solves the freezing problem?

Comment: I added some code to my post, it works now, my application does not freeze, because I separate the service/db from updating the GUI. But the problem is, that I need the reference of my Controllerclass and my stuff from DB. Now I'm passing it through the Object in the method, actually I don't think, that it is a good idea.
How can make it more flexible? The problem is, I need to put the `Platform.runLater()` in the run() Method, because the thread would run parallel and I won't access it from outside.

Comment: You could make an interface, have you done that before? If you do this then make your Controller class `implement` your interface, and make a method in your Loader class `setListener(...)`. This way you could do something like `listener.updateGUI(newGuiFragment)`.
I'm glad it works now!

Comment: I will add an example that does this in my answer